# SonataAdminBundle show field as label

Tags: view, sonata-admin, symfony-sonata, symfony

I have enum field `status` which I want to show in `label label-info` html. Like it shows for boolean value (red or green).

In there demo they have lots of labels, but I can't find on how to add them.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to create a custom template for the field you want to customise the rendering.

For your `status` field, create a template like this :

```
// src/AcmeBundle/Resources/views/CRUD/status_field.html.twig

{% extends 'SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:base_list_field.html.twig' %}

{% block field %}
    {% set status = object.status == 1 ? 'success' : 'danger' %}
    <div>
        <span class="label label-{{ status }}">{{ object.status }}</span><br />
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

Configure it as template in your admin class :

```
$listMapper
    // ...
    ->add('status', null, array(
        'template' => 'AcmeBundle:CRUD:status_field.html.twig'
    ))
```

Explained in the little but helpful [part of the documentation](https://sonata-project.org/bundles/doctrine-orm-admin/master/doc/reference/list_field_definition.html#custom-template).

Answer (score 2):

I actually tested with the sonata admin Bundle version 2.3.3, and it's as easy as this:

```
/**
 * @param ListMapper $listMapper
 */
protected function configureListFields(ListMapper $listMapper)
{
    $listMapper
        ->add('status', 'boolean');
}
```

in your admin class.

The custom template works but it is not necessary in this case as it already implemented. The vendor template is located in `vendor/sonata-project/admin-bundle/Resources/views/CRUD/list_boolean.html.twig`.

Comment: I don't given this alternative because I think the owner know that he can hard-define the type of the field. Thank you for the complement.